# Is it possible to 'burn out' a PS3 remote by charging from a PC USB slot?

Tags: pc, ps3, controllers

Is is possible to use my PS3 remote without charging the battery?  I use my ps3 remote as it is plugged into the USB port and I notice that it is automatically charging my remote battery.  Is it possible to keep my ps3 remote plugged in without charging the battery while using MotioninJoy?

Comment: I'm sure the controller's circuitry will draw power through the USB port instead of the battery if the battery is already fully charged.

Answer (score 1):

Quick battery lesson:
Modern Li-Ion batteries work this way. They charge up to 98-99% of their power cells , disconnect briefly, discharge, then recharge and so on. This happens due to the internal circuitry in order to protect overcharging and damaging the cells. Usually, you can't see this process on indicators, but it's there.

The no 1 enemy of Li-Ion batteries is extreme battery state (over or under charged) closely followed by too many recharge cycles and heat.

Like all things, the circuits are not perfect and residual currents may still pass into your battery when it's in the "discharge" state.

Some devices power themselves mostly from USB when they "recharge", like @Jeff Mercado said, but they still retain the "on off then on again" recharge behaviour.

**In your case**, that's why the battery seems to recharge when the remote is connected to the PS3. I don't know if the PS3 stock firmware has any options regarding USB power supplying, but I think custom ones do. It could be worth checking the PS3 settings if anything about recharging appears.